# Using enum instance inner class in a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, enums

I am trying to use enum element methods inside a jsp.

This is my enum:

```
public enum someEnum {
   INSTANCE {
      public String someMethod() {
          return "yay";
      }
   }
   public abstract String someMethod();
}
```

And in my jsp I want to do:

```
${somethingContainingMyEnum.getSomeEnum().someMethod()}
```

However, I get

Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class ... with modifiers "public"

I have found a workaround just doing an indirection:

```
${somethingContainingMyEnum.doSomething()}
```

and

```
public String doSomething {
   return getSomeEnum().someMethod();
}
```

Buy I would like to do it without the indirection. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a weird enum, they normally look like this :

```
public enum SomeEnum {
  INSTANCE("yay");
  private String myStr;
  SomeEnum(String myStr){
      this.myStr = myStr;
  }
  public String getMyStr(){
  return this.myStr;
  };
}
```

and you would then reference in JSP

```
${myBean.EnumInstance.MyStr}
```

There is no such thing as an anonymous method in Java. Are you thinking of anonymous inner classes ?  It seems like over complicating things.

Comment: I simplified the case a bit. I want to have different instances which calculate different logic, that's why I implement methods inside the instance

Comment: @Guito  use an abstract class or an interface instead ?

Comment: I know the exact number of instances that there are going to exist in compilation time. I think a class does not fit in here.